# How to push an object which hold states into state Array using useState hook in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, frontend

So, I need to make as much dynamic solution as possible for this issue.
I have two states (strings), that needs to be values of an object.
Then I have to push that object into and array and set state with that array as new value.

I have managed do do it, but something is wrong, every time I add an object to the array with spread operator, the state is first empty, and then starts to add previous value, not the one inserted at that moment.
export default function EqtConnect() {

```
let allSizes = [];

const [eqt_ID, setEqtID] = useState('');

const [eqtSizes, setEqtSizes] = useState([]);

const [sizeID, setSizeID] = useState(null);
const [sizeAmout, setSizeAmont] = useState(null);

/**
 * Token
 */
const { token } = useToken();

/**
 * Styles
 */
const classes = useStyles();

/**
 * handleSubmit function handle submit to API
 * @param {event object} e 
 */
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('Na submit ', eqtSizes)


    sendData({
        eqt_ID,
        eqtSizes,
        token,
    });
}


const addSize = (el) => {

    console.log(sizeID, sizeAmout); // Console logs good output
    setEqtSizes([...eqtSizes, { 'equipment_size_id': sizeID, 'quantity': sizeAmout }]); 
    // First time output is [ { 'equipment_size_id': undefined, 'quantity': undefined }]
    // Second  time output is [ { 'equipment_size_id': '--- previous value ---, 'quantity': --- previous value --- }]
    console.log('State of array', eqtSizes);
}

return (
    <>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                    <h1>Equipment</h1>
                    <Typography>
                        Connect Data
                    </Typography>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                <form action="" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)} id="send-image">
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                        <Grid container spacing={3}>

                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                                <TextField id="bikePrice" name="price" label="ID Opreme" onChange={(e) => setEqtID(e.target.value)} />
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>

                                <Box className="input-holder">
                                    <input type="number" name="sizeID" id="sizeID" onChange={e => setSizeID(parseInt(e.target.value))} />
                                    <input type="number" placeholder="Kolicina" onChange={e => setSizeAmont(parseInt(e.target.value))} />

                                    <span className="add-button" onClick={(e) => addSize(e.target)} >+</span>

                                </Box>

                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>
                    </Paper>
                    <br />

                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
                            Update
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </>

)
```

}

[image: Here is output]

Comment: Could you make a codepen of this?

Comment: I have not used it. It would take a bit to post it... @RichardHpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not actually guaranteed that the contents of the state variable managed by `useState` will be updated immediately after calling its setter. `eqtSizes` will only be brought in sync with the value you passed to `setEqtSizes` on the next render.

See [this FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function).

So, it is expected that your second log statement will show the stale value.

Comment: I made a work-around with filter method. First thing I used useEffect to set an initial state, then, I filtered ARRAY to return all but first item. Then I append to form... And it worked. Thank you

Comment: Glad it worked :)
One thing to note is that appending the state manually in the same function where you're already setting it is a bit of a code smell. You're better off using an `useEffect` function which has `eqtsizes` as its dependency to do the appending, then you don't need to filter.

Comment: Something like
`useEffect(() => {
  append(eqtSizes)
}, [eqtSizes])`